# Coalescing the Rows based on occurence and while maintaining unique values in a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

DataFrame:

```
Name         Category        Port          Class
A                Code         443        string1
A                Code          80        string2
B                Math         443        string3
A                Code         443        string1
B                Math          80        string4
```

Code that I have tried:

```
df1 = df.name.ne(df.name.shift())
count = df.name.groupby(df1.cumsum()).size()
```

Output that I got:

```
Name     Category      Port       Class     Count
A            Code       443     string1         2
B            Math       443     string3         1
A            Code       443     string1         1
B            Math        80     string4         1
```

The output that I want:

```
Name    Category         Port               Class   Count
A           Code      443, 80    string1, string2       2
B           Math          443             string3       1
A           Code          443             string1       1
B           Math           80             string4       1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` and `agg` with the appropriate functions should get you what you want. The below uses `list` which will result in all values being kept, if you only want the unique ones you can change this to `set`.

```
df['cumsum'] = df.Name.ne(df.Name.shift()).cumsum()
df2 = df.groupby(df["cumsum"]).agg({'Name': 'first', 'Category': 'first', 'Port': list, 'Class': [list, 'count']})
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(1).values[:-1].tolist() + ['Count']
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This will give you:

```
  Name  Category       Port               Class  Count
0    A      Code  [443, 80]  [string1, string2]      2
1    B      Math      [443]           [string3]      1
2    A      Code      [443]           [string1]      1
3    B      Math       [80]           [string4]      1
```

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to idendify consecutive lines with common name and category. A simple trick is to use `shift` and `cumsum`:

```
x = pd.Series(np.where((df['Name'] == df1['Name'])&(df['Category'] == df1['Category']), 0, 1),
              index = df.index).cumsum()
```

Once this is done, a `groupby` and `agg` does the job:

```
df.assign(Count=1, Port=df['Port'].astype(str)).groupby(['Name', 'Category',x]).agg(
    {'Port': ', '.join, 'Class': ', '.join, 'Count': 'sum'}).reset_index().drop(columns='level_2')
```

It gives:

```
  Name Category     Port             Class  Count
0    A     Code  443, 80  string1, string2      2
1    A     Code      443           string1      1
2    B     Math      443           string3      1
3    B     Math       80           string4      1
```